# make any internet-accessing python code work (proxy + custom .crt)

Tags: python, http-proxy

### The situation

If the following is not done, all outgoing HTTP or HTTPS requests made with python ends in a WinError 10054 Connection Reset, or a SSL bad handshake error.

1. set the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY environment variable, or their counterparts
2. What needs to be verified must be verified with a custom .crt file.

For example, assuming the .crt file is in place, both gets me a `200 OK`:

```
import os
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = #some_appropriate_address
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = #some appropriate_address
requests.get('http://www.google.com',verify="C:\the_file.crt") # 200 OK
requests.get('http://httpbin.org',verify=False) # 200 OK, but unsafe
requests.get('http://httpbin.org') # SSL bad handshake error
```

### The Problem

There is this massive jumble of pre-written code (heavily utilizing urllib3 and requests and possibly other pieces of internet-accessing code) I have, and I have to make it work under the conditions outlined above.

Sure, I can write `verify='C:\the_file.crt'` for every `requests.get()`, but that can very quickly get hairy, right? And the code may also be using some other library (that is not requests). So I am looking for a **global setting** (environment variable etc.) I should alter, so that everything works well (return a 200 OK upon a GET request to a server, whether or not the code is written in requests-py).

Also, if there is no such way, I would like an explanation as to why.

### What I tried (am trying)

Maybe editing the .condarc file (via `conda --config`) is a solution. I tried, to no avail: python gives me a "SSL verification failed" error. On the contrary, note that the code snippet above gave me a `200 OK`. To my knowledge, this does not fit nicely with many situations that were previously discussed in Stack Overflow.

By the way, setting ssl_verify to `false` does not solve the problem either; I still get a bad handshake error for some reason.

I am using Win 10, Python 3.7.4 (Anaconda).

### Update

I have edited the question to prevent future misunderstandings about the content of this question. A few answers below are a reiteration of what was written here from the start.

The current answers are not entirely satisfactory either, as they only seem to address the case where I am using `requests` or `urllib3`.

Comment: Does your environment variable not accomplish what you ask? Try lower case `https_proxy` too.

Comment: @tripleee nope, Still gets me a SSL bad handshake error.

Comment: does curl command work on command line?

Comment: @wishmaster curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

Comment: Assuming you can ping the website, try to `requests.get('http://httpbin.org',verify=False)` and post  error in question

Comment: @wishmaster this does not give me an error, but a 200 OK. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get any python code that uses the requests module(which is inside urllib3) to work behind a proxy without modifying the python code itself by setting the following environment variables in Windows.

```
http_proxy           http://[<user>:<pwd>@]<http_host>:<http_port>  
https_proxy          http://[<user>:<pwd>@]<https_host>:<https_port>
requests_ca_bundle   <path_to_ca_bundle.crt>
curl_ca_bundle       <path_to_ca_bundle.crt>
```

You can set environment variables by doing the following:

- Press Windows-Key + R, enter sysdm.cpl ,3 (mind the space before the comma) and press Enter
- Click the Environment variables button
- In either of the fields (User variables or System variables), add the four variables

Comment: Once I get to work on Monday and this works, I will hand over the bounty right away. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to add that some other tools may have different config. For example if you use TensorFlow datasets: tf.data.Dataset,you will need to setup other env variables: export TFDS_CA_BUNDLE=path/ca_certs, export TFDS_HTTPS_PROXY="http://user:password@ip:port/", export TFDS_HTTP_PROXY="http://user:password@ip:port/"
working with proxy is not easy. I am doing ML in a compny using proxy since year and I probably have issue with proxy almost every single day. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

According to Doc in Requests:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

you can use proxy in this way:

`proxies = { 'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128', 'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',}
requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)`

Then depending on if you want to add `.crt` or `.pem`:

`requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', cert=('/path/server.crt', '/path/key'))`

`requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', cert='/path/client.pem')`

https://2.python-requests.org//en/v1.0.4/user/advanced/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, the way my question was phrased might have brewed some misunderstandings. I will edit my question in the next twenty-four hours to ensure that such misunderstandings are not incurred again. When I do, I will delete/repost or edit this comment so that you can be notified. I am deeply sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - fixed the question; please take a look. Your answer is partly a reiteration of the question, and 100% not what I was looking for; I already had stated in the previous version that I needed a *global* setting. To prevent further misunderstandings, I have shortened the question, while preserving all core content.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make https requests to an outer url and you need to provide the proper certificate files for verification. You are trying to make these configurations inside each component. But I would suggest that you make those configurations globally and system-wide so neither of the components need to provide certificates and deal with ssl-verification stuff.

I am awful at windows related networking configurations, but I would suggest you go check [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/) and I am pretty sure you can configure a ssl proxy with proper certificates.